# ASMX web service Enum not retaining its value

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, .net-2.0, asmx

I have created a web service containing an enum with values as follows

```
public enum DesignChoice
{            
    DesignerChoice = 1,
    CustomerChoice = 2,
    AdditionalDesign=3,
}
```

When I add a reference to my client website, enum values are changed as in the following code:

`(int)DesignChoice.AdditionalDesign` returns 2 but I am expecting it to be 3.

I have tried the serialization attributes `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute()]` out of nowhere but had no luck.

WSDL of the service describes the enum as follows:

```
 <s:simpleType name="DesignChoice">
        <s:restriction base="s:string">
          <s:enumeration value="DesignerChoice" />
          <s:enumeration value="CustomerChoice" />
          <s:enumeration value="AdditionalDesign" />
        </s:restriction>
      </s:simpleType>
```

When I press F12 on class name in VS it shows me the following code generated from meta data:

```
public enum DesignChoice
    {
        DesignerChoice = 0,
        CustomerChoice = 1,
        AdditionalDesign = 2,
    }
```

I am using Visual Studio 2005 and .NET 2.0.

Comment: Are you sure you call the correct page? I did a quick test and it returns 3 as expected. Just to remember: you should not use Response.Write in asp.net. Can you debug your code?

Comment: yes i did debugging, but values are the same

Comment: by the way why don't to  use Response.Write?

Comment: Do you have another DesignChoice implementation in your code? Press F12 to get to the definition when the cursor is over DesignChoice. Have a look at your generated HTML, then you know why you should not use Response.Write. The output is at the top. I assume you have an .aspx page as well (?)

Comment: Sounds like you've got an old build, or something like that.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the reference and then adding it back?

Comment: yes, i have created a  new test web site, added reference but same result

Comment: some info at this thread may help? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/e844d7e1-cdf3-4631-82e0-e1a096e91d7e/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the detail explanation what's going on

http://www.kerrywong.com/2006/11/09/be-careful-when-using-enums-in-web-services/

Answer (score 2):

The values sent to and from your service will be the string that represents your Enum, for example `<DesignChoice>CustomerChoice</DesignChoice>`.

The value of this within your service should be correct but as the numerical information on any client may be different, the value on the client could be anything. As long as they send back the correct string value, this shouldn't matter. If the client is relying on the numbering explicitly, there is probably a design flaw in the client, or your service is expecting the integer for a call when it should expect the Enum.

Comment: but we need numeric values in this specific case