# Web Services Error Generating XML in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xml, web-services, exception, xamarin, asmx

I'm trying to send an array of custom objects to a web method (.asmx) but it's throwing a serialization error. The web method works fine when called from a web project but Xamarin is struggling with it and *When I click "show details" xamarin throws its own error with "illegal characters in path"* which isn't helping my debug efforts.

As far as I can tell there are no 'illegal characters' within the properties of the custom object; they are all base types such as int, string etc.

**Has anyone encountered this, or know how I can debug this?**

Complete error message:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException has been thrown
    There was an error generating the XML document.
```

Occurrs at this code snippet (from Reference.cs generated by the web reference):

```
        public void InsertClockEntries(ClockentryPublicInfo[] entries) {
            this.Invoke("InsertClockEntries", new object[] {
                        entries});
        }
```

EDIT: Here's the stack trace from Android Log:

```
E/mono-rt ( 6638): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: '10' is not a valid value for MobileTimeClock.secure.timedock.com.v2.ClockingAction.

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.EnumMap.GetXmlName (System.String typeName, System.Object enumValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.GetEnumXmlValue (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.GetStringValue (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData type, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WritePrimitiveValueLiteral (System.Object memberValue, System.String name, System.String ns, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping mappedType, System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, Boolean wrapped, Boolean isNullable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteMemberElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapElementInfo elem, System.Object memberValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteElementMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map, System.Object ob, Boolean isValueList) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteObjectElementElements (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteObjectElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob, System.String element, System.String namesp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteObject (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob, System.String element, System.String namesp, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType, Boolean writeWrappingElem) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteMemberElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapElementInfo elem, System.Object memberValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteListContent (System.Object container, System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData listType, System.Xml.Serialization.ListMap map, System.Object ob, System.Text.StringBuilder targetString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteMemberElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapElementInfo elem, System.Object memberValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteElementMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map, System.Object ob, Boolean isValueList) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map, System.Object ob, Boolean isValueList) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteMessage (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMembersMapping membersMap, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteRoot (System.Object ob) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize (System.Object o, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter writer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize (System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter, System.Object o, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

E/mono-rt ( 6638):   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Se
```

Comment: What is the type of MobileTimeClock.secure.timedock.com.v2.ClockingAction ?

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Well that's a much better starting point thankyou! (and sorry I needn't have posted so hastily). It's an Enumeration type.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was being caused by an enumerable with integer values. The values don't get exposed through the web service.

[SO answer with link to explain how enumerables lose their value in web services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12251592/2247427)

So an enum like this:

```
Public Enum ClockAction
   IN = 10
   OUT = 20
End Enum
```

Will get exposed as an enum without values, like this:

```
Public Enum ClockAction
   IN
   OUT
End Enum
```

We had the values stored as integers in a SQLite database and were trying to convert them back into the `ClockAction` enum at the point of serializing objects for our web service. This is why it was failing.